# How to set the session storage value to the drop down select field in angular JS

Tags: angularjs, select, dropdown

I am facing a issue in setting the value of the drop down field using Angular JS.
Below is the HTML and js code that I have. I am using https://select2.org/  ( select drop down component ).

```
                  <div class="dropdown">
                    <label class="label"
                      >Type of card</label
                    >
                    <select
                      class="select js-select2"
                      ng-model="cardInfo.cardType"
                      required
                    >
                      <option value="debit">Debit card</option>
                      <option value="credit">Credit card</option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                </div>

JS :

var saveToStorage = function() {
        var state = {
          cardInfo: $scope.cardInfo
        };
        window.sessionStorage.setItem("wizard", JSON.stringify(state));
      };

      var loadStorage = function() {
        var state = window.sessionStorage.getItem("wizard");
        if (state) {
          var newState = JSON.parse(state);
          $scope.cardInfo= newState.cardInfo;
         console.log('$scope.cardInfo', $scope.cardInfo.cardType ); // prints cardType: "Debit card"
        }
      };

      var init = function() {

        loadStorage();
      };
```

I am setting the value of cardType in session storage and it is getting set correctly , but the problem I am facing in binding the value to the drop down component, it is getting set to the default first option always irrespective of what I select.
In fact, I tried to display the ng-model value in HTML , its getting displayed the correct value whatever is set in session , but just the drop down doesnt get set with the session value.

Comment: try creating a demo to reproduce it

Comment: Have to invoke `init()` which in turn invokes the `loadStorage()` and sets `$scope.cardInfo`

Answer (score 0):

```
Because you have to add 
ng-init when you initialize the drop-down.



Add html code:
<div class="dropdown" ng-init="init()">
                    <label class="label"
                      >Type of card</label
                    >
                    <select
                      class="select js-select2"
                      ng-model="cardInfo.cardType"
                      required
                    >
                      <option value="debit">Debit card</option>
                      <option value="credit">Credit card</option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                </div>



js code:
$scope.saveToStorage = function() {
        var state = {
          cardInfo: $scope.cardInfo
        };
        window.sessionStorage.setItem("wizard", JSON.stringify(state));
      };
      var loadStorage = function() {
        var state = window.sessionStorage.getItem("wizard");
        if (state) {
          var newState = JSON.parse(state);
          $scope.cardInfo= newState.cardInfo;
         console.log('$scope.cardInfo', $scope.cardInfo.cardType ); // prints cardType: "Debit card"
        }
      };
      $scope.init = function() {
        loadStorage();
      };
```